# When saying var something = null is there still a space carved out in memory for the variable even though the value of null is nothing

Tags: javascript, memory, null

"In JavaScript, when we create variables, functions, or anything you can think of, the JS engine allocates memory for this and releases it once it's not needed anymore. Allocating memory is the process of reserving space in memory, while releasing memory frees up space, ready to be used for another purpose."

I know that the way the interpreter stores null is 000 which is a "bug" because null typeof is an object.

But when you declare var something = null
is there space allocated to memory because you have declared a variable even though the value of null is nothing.

I understand primitive values are allocated on the stack, objects/arrays are located on the heap.

So what happens when null is assigned to a variable?  Does the variable have a reference to an empty object on the heap? How does this cycle work?

Comment: Well it does remember it's null

Comment: The system has to remember that "if anybody asks about a variable called `something`, its value is `null`." How it does this is an implementation detail. Maybe it allocates some memory, puts a sticker called `something` on it, and sets the memory equal to something that means "this is null". Or maybe it just finds all the places where somebody asks about the value of `something` and changes them all to `null`. The language doesn't require anything specific. As long as the implementation can produce `null` when somebody asks "What is the value of `something`?"